# Erro "required int" ao executar código

Tags: java

Fiz este pequeno programa, onde pretendo que faça um loop, enquanto o utilizador optar por registar mais mensagens.

O erro, após compilar o código, diz:

> required:int
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argumente lists differ in lenght.

Aqui esta o trecho do código:

```
/*
 * Class do registo de mensagens
 */
import java.util.*;
public class RegistoDeMenssagem1 
{           
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {  
       System.out.println("Bem vindo Utilizador"); 
        System.out.println("Introduza o número da recarga"); 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
         int Recarga = kb.nextInt();  //criar o mêtodo que verifica se trata-se de int.
        String resposta;
        boolean sn;

     {
    System.out.println("Têm mais recarga para registar?");   
    System.out.println("responda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar");
     resposta = kb.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (resposta.equals("s")) 
        {
            sn = true;
            System.out.println("Introduza o número da recarga"); 
            Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int MaisRecarga = kb.nextInt(); //Aqui criar o exception handler que verifique tratar-se de int.
        System.out.println("Têm mais alguma recarga para registar?");   

    } 
    else if (resposta.equals("n"))
        {
            System.out.println("Obrigado, atê a próxima!");
                System.exit();
    }
     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Em que linha o erro estoura?

Comment: o erro estoura em java:32

Comment: E qual é a linha 32 deste código?

Comment: A linha 32 do código é: System.exit();

Comment: Amigo bom dia, o metodo exit(), recebe um parametro do tipo int, por isso o erro, tenta usar System.exit(0);

Comment: Conseguí resolver o erro mas não o meu problema. ou seja, pretendo que pela opção "n" o programa faça um loop. Agradecido.

Comment: @cambine como a duvida era sobre o erro, a pergunta já até foi respondida, o aconselhado é que você crie uma nova pergunta informando o outro problema que está enfrentando. Você pode aceitar uma das respostas abaixo também, para marcar este problema(o do erro) como solucionado.

Answer (score 3):

A chamada do método estático [`System.exit(int status)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) exige que seja passado um tipo `int` como argumento, que identifica o tipo do status de término da execução.

Se o término foi normal(não foi por causa de alguma exceção ou outra situação não esperada), você pode passar `0` como argumento. Se houve algum erro, pode-se passar outro valor diferente de zero.

Altere esta linha para `System.exit(0);`, já que pelo seu código, o problema está encerrando normalmente.

---

**Referências:**

- [Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434619/5524514)
- [Class System(Documentaçao)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Answer (score 2):

tente isto:

```
System.exit(0);
```

ele espera um parametro int para executar

Olhe:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Agradecido. santa estupidez foi a minha.

Comment: Não é estupidez sua, você está certo em tirar sua duvida